# problem with opening link through safari with webview

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uiwebview

hi i had encounter a problem opening a web link through safari. this is my code

header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface qrcode_info : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *Web;



@end



//main file


#import "qrcode_info.h"


@implementation qrcode_info
@synthesize Web;



-(BOOL)Web:(UIWebView *)Web shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    //return NO;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Web  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"help" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
    //self.wvTutorial = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@”WebView” bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)Web:(UIWebView *)Web shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

should be

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
```

You can't change the signature of a delegate method and expect it to be called.

Comment: fluchtpunk how do i do an alert before going to safari ?

Comment: create a UIAlertView (see the documentation) with a `cancel` and `open` button. Set the alerts delegate as self and implement the  `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method. check which button was clicked and do whatever you want. UIAlertViews are really easy.